# Dynamically render image based on model element

Tags: c#, html, image, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I have a View model which contains a list of strings that I want to use to dynamically render some images to a razor view.

`public List<string> States { get; set; } = new List<string>() { "ACT", "NSW", "NT", "QLD", "SA", "TAS", "VIC", "WA" };`

This is what I am doing:

```
@foreach (var state in Model.States)
  {
    var stateImage = $"~/Images/{state}.jpg";

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-6 pb-4 card-deck">
            <div class="card">
                   <img src="@stateImage" class="card-img" />
            </div>
     </div>
}
```

The issue Im having is that the image does not render. If I hardcode the path ("~/Images/ACT.jpg" for
example) then it works perfectly and the image loads and if I observe it through debugger or even just display it on a div then it shows the exact same thing I am hardcoding yet it still doesnt render the image and i am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` needs to be evaluated in the same way as the code. It can't be parsed as Razor syntax if it is assigned to a string variable. And in your example, the use of a string variable is unnecessary anyway.

Try this:

```
@foreach (var state in Model.States)
{
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-6 pb-4 card-deck">
            <div class="card">
                   <img src="~/Images/@stateImage" class="card-img" />
            </div>
     </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly, i feel silly now for such an easy fix!